# App shown as not compatible

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I just uploaded my game I made with Unity to Google Play.
After doing all the submission work (screenshots, etc) - my app got listed, but almost any device gets the message "Your device is not compatible"

This is my Unity setup:

[image]

And this is how I exported the apk:

[image]

So why do you think, this happens?

[Here is the link to the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Areon.ShuttleUp)

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Now, that I uploaded 2 apks (one with dxt compression, one without anything) it works.
But the users only can downloaded the version without compression, and that looks bad.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity settings, but as a guess: maybe setting the device filter as "ARMv7 only" is the cause? Shouldn't it be the "minimum" version and not "only" one?

Comment: I have no other option there.

Comment: Have you tried changing the Texture Compression to ETC1? [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/206088-Google-Play-Store-quot-not-compatible-with-this-device-quot) it says it makes a difference.

Comment: Didn't make a difference

Comment: Galaxy S3 Mini - the one I used to develop

Comment: FWIW, it says it is compatible with my device (Galaxy S3 [not mini])

Comment: Can you download and play it?

Comment: Yup works fine, though I can't work out what I'm meant to do :P

Comment: Do the devices it does not work on appear in the list of supported devices?

Comment: Yes, they do. I double checked it.